# How to add a reshape layer to the start of a pre-trained CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using a pre-trained Inception V3 model for a facial recognition task. However, I would like to add a Reshape layer at the start of this model to convert the example into a tensor of different shape that is then fed through the pre-trained model. I know there's a way to configure the Input shape for the Inception V3 using the `input_shape` argument for the constructor:

`inception_model = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))`

But that doesn't solve my problem. Due to technical constraints reasons, I expect my model to receive a vector of `(150528, 1, 1)` and would like to reshape this into `(224, 244, 3)` before passing it into my model.

So, something like:

```
reshape_layer = Reshape((224, 224, 3), input_shape=(150528,1,1))
inception_model = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
# join the reshape layer to ensure input passes through reshape_layer and into inception_model

# then I have my custom layers after that
head_model = inception_model.output
head_model = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)

# ...and so on
```

I'm new to Tensorflow and a bit stuck, would appreciate if folks could suggest there's a way to include this transformation layer on top of the pre-trained model. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, I cannot, unfortunately use `image.reshape` or `tf.image.resize` but have to perform the resizing via a transformation layer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your data input to shape (224, 224, 3), you can check the shape of data and using assert you can check it whether it equals to 224*224*3. If it's so, then modify it as such, otherwise, it will raise an error. The input data should be divisible by 224*224*3 to reshape it into this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))` ,may solve your problem.
For more use [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)

Comment: I agree that would be a valid approach, but I need to fix this problem using a layer in the NN and cannot have any data preprocessing before feeding the example through the network

Comment: For standard layer, you can use this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape)  but for pre-trained models, I don't know . Maybe others can help you